# Distribution of Salesforce Platform License for AppExchange App

Tags: appexchange, licenses, isv, order, oem

We currently started selling an app through the AppExchange and I couldn't find any information as to what needs to be done in order to get Salesforce Platform Licenses.

My understanding is that when submitting an order using the Channel Order App, the licenses, if any, are automatically added to the target client Org based on the products in the order. Unfortunately, we cannot test this without submitting an order.

I was wondering if there was any in depth information about how this work (I couldn't find any a part from quick mention of those elements in some DreamForce video on YouTube)?

Also, is there any difference between submitting an order for license for a customer that is already with Salesforce but looking for Platform licenses only for our App and a customer who is completely new to Salesforce and looking only for our licenses? The difference seems to be simply the concept of ISV vs OEM deployment, but OEM only state that its *ideal* for new customer but there is no mention that an app initial developed for an OEM deployment cannot be simply deployed to an existing functioning Org.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closing this question as I forgot about it but got the answer. Hope it might help some other people maybe later.

> My understanding is that when submitting an order using the Channel Order App, the licenses, if any, are automatically added to the target client Org based on the products in the order. Unfortunately, we cannot test this without submitting an order.

Correct. This is exactly how it works. Basically, when making an ISV/OEM contract and linking it to the Channel Order App, products will be associated on Salesforce side to a type of product (if any) to deliver to the targeted org of the order. This cannot be seen on the Product objects of the Channel Order App (unless the Representative who processed the contract added it to the description) so you need to know your contract or ask someone at Salesforce if no one knows the technical details.

> Also, is there any difference between submitting an order for license for a customer that is already with Salesforce but looking for Platform licenses only for our App and a customer who is completely new to Salesforce and looking only for our licenses? The difference seems to be simply the concept of ISV vs OEM deployment, but OEM only state that its ideal for new customer but there is no mention that an app initial developed for an OEM deployment cannot be simply deployed to an existing functioning Org.

No, there is no difference on the deliver-ability of the products between an OEM and ISV contract. Like mentioned above, its all about a product to deliver being associated to one of your products in the Channel Order App. The only difference is the terms of the contracts, for things like products and the share Salesforce take for the service provided (usually lower in ISV contracts compared to OEM one).

All this information was acquired by talking to technical people on Salesforce side and by trying it.